# How do I get the eclipse-jetty plugin to scan for and recognize websocket classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, websocket, jetty

I'm attempting to start a simple java maven webapp from eclipse Indigo containing only one class, a basic annotated websocket.  I would like annotation scanning to identify and register the class automatically using the sourceforge eclipse-jetty [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-jetty/) which is configured to use my own local jetty distribution 9.1.1.v20140108.  Code for the websocket is as follows:

```
package com.myapp.websocket_sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/broadcast", encoders = {}, decoders = {})
public class TestWebsocket {
    private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestWebsocket.class);

    public TestWebsocket() {
        logger.info("Initializing websocket.");
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(final Session session) {
        logger.info("Opening new websocket session.");
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(final Session session) {
        logger.info("Closing new websocket session.");
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final String message, final Session client) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        logger.info("Got message {}.", message);
        for (final Session session : sessions) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When starting under eclipse-jetty, the websocket class is apparently not being identified and scanned by jetty.  In looking at the (auto-generated) jetty.xml used by eclipse-jetty plugin, the class appears to be on the extraClasspath option.

```
<Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Arg type="String">src/main/webapp</Arg>
        <Arg type="String">/ws-sample</Arg>
        <Set name="extraClasspath">C:/Users/padolan/AppData/Local/eclipse-workspaces/websockets/websocket-sample/target/classes;C:/Users/padolan/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar;C:/Users/padolan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar</Set>
    </New>
</Set>
```

I can take the same project (built as a war file using maven), copy it to the jetty distribution's webapps folder, and start it using the jetty start.jar like so, and the websocket is picked up and made available:

```
java -jar start.jar --module=webapp,websocket
```

I suspect I need to add some special jetty configuration or additional classes to the classpath of the eclipse-jetty plugin to get it to pick up the annotated websocket class, but I'm not sure what that should be.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after piecing together solutions from various posts on configuring jetty, and through a bit of trial and error, I got this to work.  The steps I had to follow were:

1. **Create a new eclipse-jetty run configuration and point eclipse-jetty to the new jetty distribution (standard feature supported by the eclipse-jetty plugin).**
2. **Add the websocket classes (and other dependent classes) as custom classpath bootstrap entries in the eclipse-jetty plugin.**  While I ended up adding all jetty distribution jars in there, this was likely overkill and you could figure out which ones are really necessary.
3. **Create and reference a new custom jetty.xml configuration which adds the proper annotation-scanning configuration classes.**  This has to be added as another jetty context configuration in the eclipse-jetty plugin's run configuration window, below the standard 'Eclipse Jetty Launcher Context' entry (which is an auto-generated jetty.xml file that you cannot change).  The actual file I used looked like the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd" -->
<!DOCTYPE Configure [
<!ELEMENT Configure (Set*,Call*)>
<!ELEMENT Call (Arg*,Call*)>
<!ELEMENT Arg (#PCDATA|Ref|Array)*>
<!ELEMENT Array (Item+)>
<!ELEMENT Item (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Configure id CDATA "">
<!ATTLIST Configure class CDATA "">
<!ATTLIST Call class CDATA "">
<!ATTLIST Call name CDATA "">
<!ATTLIST Arg name CDATA "">
<!ATTLIST Array type CDATA "">
]>
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<Set name="configurationClasses">
<Array type="java.lang.String">
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
  <!-- <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item> -->
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
</Array>
</Set>
</Configure>
```

*Special note: I was not able to directly reference the public jetty dtd, hence I hacked together the embedded one which allowed eclipse-jetty to load the config without error*

That's it (ha)!  With this I could add new annotated websocket classes to my web project (as well as annotated servlet classes) and jetty would pick them up when started with the eclipse-jetty run configuration.